# Fresh install of ubuntu 18.04 LTS (dual boot with windows.) Keyboard does not work

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, keyboard

Just finished dual booting ubuntu, but my laptop keyboard does not work. External keyboards do, I have tried updating/reinstalling `xserver-xorg-input-all`, doing ctrl-alt-F3 on login screen (on external kb) takes me to terminal in which the builtin kb works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your laptop's name and model?

Comment: Its a Dell XPS 15, 9575

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the problem and a (extremely hacky) solution. It seems that because my laptop is a 2 in 1, it starts in tablet mode, where the keyboard is ignored. My solution to this is to briefly put it into actual tablet mode, then fold it back. This does some black magic and now it believes that it is in laptop mode, obviously this is not ideal so I will leave this open.